# Перезапись всех существующих номеров телефона в другом формате

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

Таблица с клиентами у которых номера телефонов в абсолютно разных форматах.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно накатить миграцию чтобы все существующие номера телефонов перезаписались в формат +###########. Без ()-/ и знаков после х включительно

Сам вопрос. Как правильно написать запрос?

Comment: Очистить от всего, кроме цифр (regexp_replace). Если нет кода страны - добавить. Добавить плюс. Элементарно же...

Comment: @Akina Должно быть что-то вроде SELECT regexp_replace(phone, '(???)', '[0-9]') FROM table; ?

Comment: @Akina могу попросить подправить запрос? С регулярками беда(

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/0hk2Zr_a

Comment: @Akina правильно ли я понимаю, что этот запрос не перезаписывает существующие данные в базе, а лишь форматирует вывод этих данных?

Comment: Именно так. Надо изменить данные по месту - используйте соответствующий UPDATE.